# what is the difference between the following code in styled component attribute assignment?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Between 1 and 2 below, what is the difference in assigning the attribute to the HTML element?
I used 2 and it suddenly stopped working. 1 seems to work fine.
I do not know why 2 does not work anymore?

The error I get when using 1 is :
`Invalid value for prop size on the tag <input>. Either remove them from the element or pass  a string or number value to them in the DOM`

```
//1
const Input = styled.input.attrs(props => ({
    size: props.small ? 5 : undefined,
 }))`

//2
const Input = styled.input.attrs({
    size: (props) => props.small ? 5 : undefined,
 }))`
```

Comment: Works for me - https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-bassi-kqfx3?file=/src/index.js. The seconds seems wrong because `attrs` should receive a function, not an object.

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate. However, strangely, the second seems to work too. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-paper-en17z?file=/src/index.js